# running into issues during TF Apply terraform lakeformation permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-lake-formation

I want to create `aws_lakeformation_permissions` for an IAM role(iam_glue_runner_role) with SELECT permissions on all the tables within the given database(db_catalog_name). This database is already registered in the lakeformation, and I am using `wildcard = true` expression to grant SELECT access.

```
resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "lf_glue_runner_all_table_permission" {
  permissions = ["SELECT"]
  principal   = var.iam_glue_runner_role

  table {
    database_name = var.db_catalog_name
    wildcard =  true
  }
}
```

However, TF apply fails with the error -

> Error: error creating Lake Formation Permissions (input: {\n
> Permissions: ["SELECT"],\n  Principal: {\n
> DataLakePrincipalIdentifier:
> "arn:aws:iam:::role/iam_glue_runner_role"\n  },\n
> Resource: {\n    Table: {\n        DatabaseName:
> "<database_name>",\n      TableWildcard: {\n\n      }\n    }\n
> }\n}): AccessDeniedException: Resource does not    exist or requester
> is not authorized to access requested permissions

This is terraform module link - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lakeformation_permissions#wildcard

Just want to point out that similar resource when executed at just the database level(not the table level access) succeeds -

```
resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "lf_glue_runner_select_permission" {
  principal   = var.iam_glue_runner_role
  permissions = ["ALL"]

  database {
    name       = var.db_catalog_name
  }
}
```

This makes me wonder if I am using `wildcard` entry right but I do not see what could go wrong in that expression (`wildcard = true`)

Comment: What does the IAM policy for the role look like?

Comment: Here we go - https://pastebin.com/6B6upBDn

Comment: Based on the docs you might need `CREATE_TABLE` permission as well.

Comment: It has `ALL` permissions in the give database(create/alter/describe etc) from the `lf_glue_runner_select_permission` resource. Just realized its not the apt naming for the resource!

Comment: Wait, what? Which example works, the first one or the second one?

Comment: second one in the question - `lf_glue_runner_select_permission `

Comment: And you want the first one to work?

Comment: yes -that's right. First resource errors out.

Comment: But it has only `SELECT` permissons or I am missing something? Have you tried adding `CREATE_TABLE` permission to that resource?

Comment: yes, I did add CREATE_TABLE but no luck with others!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249114/discussion-between-abhi-and-marko-e).